# Fragment is showing but not attached to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

Hi i am working in an app, in which:

1. View pager is there on an activity.
2. On that view pager i am showing 2 fragments(frag1 and frag2).
3. on button click on frag1 we have added one more fragment(lets say frag3).
4. and on back press on frag3 i come back on frag1.

Issue:

the issue is when i come back to frag1 from frag3 on back press, sometimes frag1 is not attached to the activity.

i am not able to figure out how this is happening.

if this is happening then what is the solution so i can stop activity to detach the frag1 or re-initialize the frag1 again.

Please help.

Comment: try adding your fragments to backstack , when u wanna save your fragment states

Comment: Use addToBackStack while creating for frag1

Comment: but frag1 is on viewpager, should i add that too? @Shane

Comment: It might be due to how you are back stacking your fragments, but this is a shot in the dark. Please go ahead and provide your code base if you are still struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> This code may help you

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  implements IconPagerAdapter {
    protected static final int[] PAGER = new int[] {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4
    };

    private int mCount = PAGER.length;

    public PagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new PagerFragment(PAGER[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
        return ICONS[index % PAGER.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

> Defining Fragments

```
public final class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "PagerFragment:Content";
    int imageSource;

    public PagerFragment(int imageSource) {
        this.imageSource = imageSource;

    }

    public PagerFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            imageSource = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.indicatorpage, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.pagerImage);
        image.setImageResource(imageSource);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY_CONTENT, imageSource);
    }
}
```

> MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    PagerFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new PagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                System.out.println("selected page is :" + position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        CirclePageIndicator mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mIndicator.setRadius(7 * density);
        mIndicator.setPageColor(0x00000000);
        mIndicator.setFillColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mIndicator.setStrokeColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mIndicator.setStrokeWidth(1 * density);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```